# Raspberry Pi: Access command line within a C/C++ program

Tags: c++, command-line, raspberry-pi

I want to know if I can call a command line function (like ls) within a c/c++ program?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [`system`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system)

Comment: It would be a big help if you could tell us which OS you are using and which compiler and maybe if you are you using any library or framework ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`popen(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    FILE *in;
    char buff[512];

    if(!(in = popen("ls -la", "r")))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL)
    {
        cout << buff;
    }

    pclose(in);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `system` function to run a bash script.

```
system("my_script.sh");
```

For details see [system - linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system)